# Динамическое формирование блоков одинаковой высоты

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Столкнулся с проблемой, как сохранять одинаковую высоту блоков без выхода текста за его пределы при масштабировании. На странице у меня есть блоки расположенные "плиткой" по три в каждом ряду. Блок имеет вид

```
<article>
    <h2>
        Title
    </h2>

    <p>
        description
        <a href="#">Read more</a>
    </p>
</article>
```

Клиенту приходит массив статей. Естественно, что из-за различного контента и высоту у блоков будет разная. Хочется, чтобы и при масштабировании у блоков была одна и та же высота. Первое, что мне пришло в голову - это при помощи jquery написать функцию, которая находит высоту максимального  и

и придают ее остальным блокам. Эта функция вызывалась бы при каждом изменении масштаба $(window).resize(myFunctionSetHeight). Но, как оказалась, она работает не совсем так, как хотелось бы. Текст может "выползать" сбоку за блок. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной задачей и как он ее решил?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать через css:

1. `flexbox` (от IE10 и вроде есть полифилы)
2. Cвязка `display:table` и `display:table-cell`, возможно потребуется ещё `table-layout:fixed`,чтобы ячейки имели одинаковую ширину.

С помощью css так же можно научить браузер [переносить слова](http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/02/word-wrap.html).

Comment: Использовать явные `<br>` не нужно. Для отделения параграфа используйте двойной перенос строки. Для форматирования списка используйте цифры с точкой и отделяйте список пустыми строками.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   var mh = 0;
   $(".catItemBody").each(function () {
       var h_block = parseInt($(this).height());
       if(h_block > mh) {
          mh = h_block;
       };
   });
   $(".catItemBody").height(mh);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Используй display:inline-block для элементов вместо float'а.

Ну и ещё можно сделать с помощью flexbox'а.